# How to send GCS audit logs to logstash?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, logstash

I am very new to GCS. kindly help me to pull complete audit logs and send it to logstash so that i can parse it and send it to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) section [Exporting audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#exporting_audit_logs):

> To export audit log entries outside of Logging, create a [logs
> sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export). Give the sink a query that specifies the audit log types you
> want to export; for query examples, go to [Security logging
> queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library#security-filters).
>
> If you want to export audit log entries for a Google Cloud
> organization, folder, or billing account, review [Aggregated
> sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks).

then move to the section [Overview of logs exports](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export):

> All logs, including audit logs, platform logs, and user logs, are sent
> to the Cloud Logging API where they pass through the Logs Router. The
> Logs Router checks each log entry against existing rules to determine
> which log entries to ingest (store), which log entries to include in
> exports, and which log entries to discard. For more details, see [Logs
> Router overview](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview).
>
> Exporting involves writing a **query** that selects the log entries you
> want to export, and choosing a **destination** in Cloud Storage, BigQuery,
> or Pub/Sub. The query and destination are held in an object called a
> **sink**. Sinks can be created in Google Cloud projects, organizations,
> folders, and billing accounts.

and

> Every time a log entry arrives in a project, folder, billing account,
> or organization resource, Logging compares the log entry to the sinks
> in that resource. Each sink whose query matches the log entry writes a
> copy of the log entry to the sink's export destination.

after that, follow instructions at the [Scenarios for exporting Cloud Logging: Elasticsearch](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-elasticsearch):

> This scenario shows **how to export selected logs from Logging to an
> Elasticsearch cluster**.

(Elasticsearch cluster could be installed from Marketplace)

as an alternative you can follow community tutorial [Exporting Stackdriver logs to Elastic Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/exporting-stackdriver-elasticcloud):

> This tutorial explains **how to export Stackdriver logs to the [Elastic
> Cloud](https://cloud.elastic.co/login)** Elasticsearch SaaS platform to perform log analytics. Elastic
> Cloud is a SaaS offering, which saves time by not needing to build and
> manage the Elasticsearch infrastructure.